# How can I determine which Android devices can use the Step Counter?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I am working on a Unity application that tracks the steps of a user. It uses an Android plugin that a previous developer had already written. This plugin accesses the [Android step counter sensor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html#TYPE_STEP_COUNTER). In the Developer portal, it is stated that it was "added in API level 19".

The step counter functionality works just fine on my OnePlus 5. Yet, I cannot find any mention of the OnePlus 5 having this sensor. It also worked on an Honor 8, and again, there is no mention of that phone having this sensor. I even contacted Huawei directly and they explicitly stated that none of their current models have the step counter sensor, only the accelerometer.

Is it possible to know which devices can be used with the current plugin? Is the step counter an actual physical sensor or a virtual one that simply uses the accelerometer? Is it limited only to certain devices or could the current plugin would work on any device running Android 4.4 or newer that has the accelerometer?

Answer (score 1):

The step counter is not a physical sensor but a virtual sensor or it is referred as a composite sensor. It uses the accelerometer and possibly other sensors if available under the hood to calculate the steps. For example, the linear acceleration sensor is another type of composite or virtual sensor which gets linear acceleration from an accelerometer by subtracting the gravity values from it.

It should work on any device with Android 4.4(and newer) which has at least an accelerometer. You can check its availability on the fly in your code (something like this):

```
Sensor countSensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER);
        if (countSensor != null) {
            sensorManager.registerListener(this, countSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Count sensor not available!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

For details on how it really works, please read this:
https://source.android.com/devices/sensors/sensor-types#step_detector
https://source.android.com/devices/sensors/sensor-types